# AWS EC2 user data - how to debug failed EFS mount failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I'm using an EFS volume on my EC2 instance (Amazon linux AMI). I can mount the volume without issue, if I shell into the server and run something like:

> sudo mount -t nfs -o
>   nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2
>   fs-xxxxxxxxx.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:/ efs

But if I add a shell script inside the user data section of my instance and the boot it, I get nothing, how can I debug it? Is there some logs or something in the filesystem I can look at? I don't get an errors, just no mounted drive. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make sure all packages are up-to-date
yum update -y

# Make sure that NFS utilities and AWS CLI utilities are available
yum install -y jq nfs-utils python27 python27-pip awscli
pip install --upgrade awscli

# Name of the EFS filesystem (match what was created in EFS)
EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_NAME="xxxx.efs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"

# Gets the EC2 availability zone for the current ECS instance

EC2_AVAIL_ZONE="ap-southeast-2b"
# Gets the EC2 region for the current ECS instance

EC2_REGION="Asia Pacific (Sydney)"

# Creates the mount-point for the EFS filesystem
DIR_TGT="efs"
mkdir "${DIR_TGT}"

# Get the EFS filesystem ID.
EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID="$(/usr/local/bin/aws efs describe-file-systems --region "${EC2_REGION}" | jq '.FileSystems[]' | jq "select(.Name==\"${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_NAME}\")" | jq -r '.FileSystemId')"

if [ -z "${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID}" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: variable not set" 1> /etc/efssetup.log
    exit
fi

# Create the mount source path
DIR_SRC="${EC2_AVAIL_ZONE}.${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID}.efs.${EC2_REGION}.amazonaws.com"

# Actually mount the EFS filesystem
mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,soft,timeo=600,retrans=2 "${DIR_SRC}:/" "${DIR_TGT}"

# Create a backup of the existing /etc/fstab
cp -p "/etc/fstab" "/etc/fstab.back-$(date +%F)"

# Add the new mount point to /etc/fstab
echo -e "${DIR_SRC}:/ \t\t ${DIR_TGT} \t\t nfs \t\t nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,soft,timeo=600,retrans=2 \t\t 0 \t\t 0" | tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Comment: `DIR_TGT="efs"` needs to be an absolute path to an existing directory, e.g. `DIR_TGT="/srv/efs"`

Answer (score 4):

you can find the `UserData` logs at `cloud-init-output.log`

```
/var/log/cloud-init.log and
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log
```

Your EC2_REGION should be `ap-southeast-2` not `Asia Pacific (Sydney)`, Since you have mentioned the Endpoint name already, you don't need to construct the EFS endpoint.

```
mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,soft,timeo=600,retrans=2 "${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_NAME}:/" "${DIR_TGT}"
```

If you want to construct it, use the following [EFS DNS Endpoint convention](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-cmd-dns-name.html):

```
file-system-id.efs.aws-region.amazonaws.com
```

So, it should be

```
DIR_SRC="${EFS_FILE_SYSTEM_ID}.efs.${EC2_REGION}.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer. I'm just working through the code right now to debug this.

Comment: Hi @Sudharsan, I cannot see anything in the logs that is related to the file system not being mounted. It does not seem to give me an error. It's just the drive is not mounted. Where else can look for this stuff?

Comment: Do you see your `echo`? you can try to run the script manually once see if there are any errors.